# Como puedo guardar diferente información en la misma posición de un ArrayList

Tags: java

Tengo información de un paciente que se guarda al principio del programa
[image: Guardar Informacion]

Tengo estas dos clases en la una se guarda los resultados y se crea un constructor y en la otra recupera el constructor y se crea una lista con ese la cual se mete en otro constructor. Este constructor es el que guardo información en la lista anterior pero sin la información de resultados
[image: Clase resultados]
[image: Clase Paciente]

Lo que necesito es guardar todo junto, donde se guardo el paciente guardar la lista de resultados para después con un botón "mostrar paciente" se imprima todo junto.
[image: Botón mostrar paciente]
[image: Imprimir]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El texto debe ir como codigo. Y creo que tenes un concepto erroneo. Tu paciente ya tiene sus resultados, que es lo que queres guardar todo junto?

Comment: Deberías tener algún enlace entre la persona y sus resultados. En la clase Resultados debería haber como atributo una persona. Así será más fácil obtener todos. Después, en el constructor de la persona, puedes llenarte un arraylist con todos los resultados de esa persona o algo así.